# How to get a paragraph in android text view?

Tags: android

I have a word document with 2 paragraph, Which include both Malayalam & Arabic letters in ASCII character set, i want to see this data in my app when pressing a button 'Read More'

Comment: I don't exactly understand what are you asking! If you have two peace of data store them separably then when you click read more add the second one to first one. textview.text = textview.text + secondText;

Comment: OK, I will explain.I am creating this app for my friend,She gave me a word document and some fonts used in it. She want to make it is an app. It is a soft copy of a book. At first it list each the chapters name on different button, And while pressing a button the app should show corresponding chapter... so how can i do this..  can u help me please, I am just a beginner..

Comment: Well you have 2 options 1)copy all data from word document to a file and format it in specific way (for example separate each paragraph by %p character!) ,so since you know the format of file you can read data from it. To get better performance you need to know about file storing, indexing, etc witch i'm not very good at personally! 2)read data from a word document, simple InputStreamReader (mentioned in second answer) is not gonna work because word document unlike .txt files doesn't store row data, it also stores formatting, metadata and most likely it using some advanced indexing techniques.

Comment: If you only deal with one word document i suggest the first option it's a simpler approach. Reading data from word documents is also possible since there are many apps that done it before. But i don't know how i can be done or how complicated it is! Figure it out yourself. good luck

Comment: oookiii... thanku sooo much fo ua help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside `onClick` method:

```
     StringBuilder stringBuilder;

     try {
        InputStream is = openFileInput("path to file");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
     }
     catch (IOException e) {}
```

Comment: I am creating this app for my friend,She gave me a word document and some fonts used in it. She want to make it is an app. It is a soft copy of a book. At first it list each the chapters name on different button, And while pressing a button the app should show corresponding chapter... so how can i do this..  can u help me please, I am just a beginner..